# .htaccess URL rewrite using wildcard string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Any URL ending with '/thank-you' should show the contents of 'www.abc.com/thank-you' page. It should not redirect, but load the contents from that page. Probably achievable with some wildcard in .htaccess file.
For example:

- www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/thank-you
- www.abc.com/a/b/thank-you
- www.abc.com/....anything.../thank-you

All these should show the content of **www.abc.com/thank-you**

I tried:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/thank-you /thank-you [L]`
in the .htaccess file. This code did not rewrite the URL.

Comment: Don't think that rewrite rule can do that. Instead you can make a php file which will load and display content of that thank-you page and make redirection to that php file.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what result you got instead of the desired. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask